# Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7.0 NSLayoutConstraint inconsistencies

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

Hi the problem is the UILabel don't show all the text between 2 Xcode Versions i put gray colored frame to show better.

This is de code:

```
    _descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [_descriptionLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    _descriptionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    [_descriptionLabel sizeToFit];

NSLayoutConstraint *descriptionTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.descriptionLabel
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:self.categoryLabel
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                 multiplier:1
                                                                   constant:0];


NSLayoutConstraint *descriptionLeading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.descriptionLabel
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                         toItem:self.segmentedControl
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                     multiplier:1
                                                                       constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *descriptionTrailing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.descriptionLabel
                                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                          toItem:self.segmentedControl
                                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                      multiplier:1
                                                                        constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *descriptionBottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.descriptionLabel
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:self.containerView
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                    multiplier:1
                                                                      constant:0];



[self addConstraints:@[descriptionTop,descriptionLeading,descriptionTrailing,descriptionBottom]];
```

And this image is from Xcode 6.4 and show all text ok

[image]

And this image is from Xcode 7.0 text show cut

[image]

Any comment is appreciated

Comment: This is unlikely to be the compiler.  Are both images from the same iOS version?

Comment: Different Xcodes, but are they also different _systems_? That's the important thing.

Comment: What is `self`? And where is all this happening? Where are the other interface objects referred to? I don't see them in your screen shots? Is a table view cell involved? Give _information_ if you want help.

Comment: Did you set `_descriptionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`?

Comment: @Paul11 is the same version of iOS but only change to Xcode 7.0

Comment: @matt it's the equal systems and same version iOS

Comment: @user3480295 if put that code the UILabel not appear :(

Comment: Sorry, I get it wrong. You should set `_descriptionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` if you are adding constraints to `_descriptionLabel`.

Comment: @user3480295 Hi i put the code but no change anything.

Comment: "it's the equal systems and same version iOS" Impossible. You're not giving sufficient or true information. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: @matt The error is reproducible i am not kidding, if use Xcode 6.4 all views show correctly.  And if I try to open the same project in Xcode 7.0 the same version and same Device all view's shows the same problem.

Comment: When you compile in Xcode 6.4 you compile against iOS 8.x. When you compile in Xcode 7 you compile against iOS 9. So you are in fact running under two different systems, _even if it's the same device_. - By the way, if you cannot, as I have requested, describe the problem in such a way that _others_ can reproduce it, it isn't reproducible. You have not made _any_ attempt to make this problem reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the debugger for warning of breaking conflicting constraints.

Either your Label has gotten its autoResizingMask converted to constraints and they conflict with those 4 constraints above, or those 4 conflict with your existing contraints in this "self" of yours.